# Java IPC w/Sockets - Using Loopback Device

Tags: java, sockets, ipc

So I'm trying to implement socket communication between processes for a project. But I can't seem to connect to any port via the loopback device. Am I missing something here? I've let this run an attempt on almost 500 ports and it always refuses to connect.

```
static final String HOST = "127.0.0.1";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int port = 1000;
    while (true) {
        try {
            socket = new Socket(HOST, PORT); // initialing the socket
            writer = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
            reader = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
            break;
        } catch (ConnectException ex) {
            System.out.println("failure on port: " + port);
            ++port; // increment port to try next 
        }
    }

    ...

};
```

Here is the entire program if anyone wants to see the declarations and whatnot.

```
package socket_ipc;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ConnectException;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Socket_IPC {
    static final int NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES = 100; // number of messages to pass
    static int[] PRODUCED_MSSG = new int[NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES]; // for comparing
    static int[] CONSUMED_MSSG = new int[NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES]; // for comparing

    static final String HOST = "127.0.0.1";    // IP address of loopback device
    static final int PORT = 1000;              // arbitrary port number (local)

    static OutputStreamWriter writer;   // write to socket
    static InputStreamReader reader;    // read from socket
    static Socket socket;               // the socket

    private static class s_Producer extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES; i++) {
                try {
                    PRODUCED_MSSG[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 256); // get data
                    writer.write(PRODUCED_MSSG[i]); // write data to the socket
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.err.println(ex.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static class s_Consumer extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES; i++) {
                try {
                    int data = reader.read();   // obtain data from the socket
                    CONSUMED_MSSG[i] = data;    // put retrieved data in array
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.err.println(ex.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int port = PORT; // beginning at 1000
        while (true) {
            try {
                socket = new Socket(HOST, port); // initialing the socket
                writer = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
                reader = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
                break;
            } catch (ConnectException ex) {
                System.out.println("failure on port: " + port);
                ++port; // increment port to try next 
            }
        }

        /* insanciating and starting the producer process */
        s_Producer p = new s_Producer();
        p.start();

        /* insanciating and starting the consumer process */
        s_Consumer c = new s_Consumer();
        c.start();

        try { /* joining threads to wait for completion */
            p.join();
            c.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.toString());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES; i++) {
            System.out.println(
                "[" + i + "]: " + PRODUCED_MSSG[i] + " == " + CONSUMED_MSSG[i]);
            if (PRODUCED_MSSG[i] != CONSUMED_MSSG[i]) {
                System.out.println("PROCESS SYNCHRONIZATION ERROR!");
            System.exit(0);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("PROCESS SYNCHRONIZATION SUCCESS!");

    }

};
```

Comment: Is there anything listening on the ports you try to connect to?

Comment: I suggest you try connecting to a port where there is a service already running. If you print the actual error it should say "Connection refused" to tell you nothing is listening on that port.

Comment: So am I not making the socket listen when I create it on that port?

Comment: May I suggest [the Oracle Java tutorial on networking and specifically client-server and sockets?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html) It's pretty comprehensive and shows a client and server pair.

Answer (score 2):

Well I'm not sure what exactly was the cause of the issue, it very well could be the use of a port number < 1024. Also, I eventually came across a great set of encapsulating readers/writers, the `DataOutputStream` and `DataInputStream` classes. These provided a much easier solution by providing specific read and write ops based on the object; such as `dis.readInt()` and `dos.writeInt(int n)`.

Here is the completed and successfully running source code:

```
package socket_ipc;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
/** Socket Inter-Process Communication.
 * Implements the Producer-Consumer Problem, using Sockets for IPC.
 * @author William Hatfield: CEG-4350-01 Fall 2015
 */
public class Socket_IPC {
    static final int NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES = 100; // number of messages to pass
    static int[] PRODUCED_MSSG = new int[NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES]; // for comparing
    static int[] CONSUMED_MSSG = new int[NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES]; // for comparing
    static final String HOST = "127.0.0.1"; // IP address of loopback device
    static final int PORT = 1234;           // arbitrary port number (local)
    static ServerSocket serverSocket;       // the shared server socket
    private static class Producer extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Socket toClient = serverSocket.accept();
                DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(toClient.getOutputStream());
                for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES; i++) {
                PRODUCED_MSSG[i] = 
                        (int)((Math.random() - .5) * Integer.MAX_VALUE);
                dos.writeInt(PRODUCED_MSSG[i]);
            }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.err.println("Producer Error: " + ex.toString());
            }
        }
    }
    private static class Consumer extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Socket fromServer = new Socket(HOST, PORT);
                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fromServer.getInputStream());
                for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES; i++) {
                CONSUMED_MSSG[i] = dis.readInt();
            }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.err.println("Consumer Error: " + ex.toString());
            }    
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
            Producer p = new Producer();    // create the producer thread
            Consumer c = new Consumer();    // create the consumer thread
            p.start();                      // start the producer thread
            c.start();                      // start the consumer thread
            p.join();                       // wait for producer thread
            c.join();                       // wait for consumer thread
        } catch (InterruptedException | IOException ex) { /* handle later */ }
         /* compare produced and consumed data, exit if any match fails */
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES; i++) {
            System.out.print("[" + i + "]: " + PRODUCED_MSSG[i]);
            System.out.println(" == " + CONSUMED_MSSG[i]);
            if (PRODUCED_MSSG[i] != CONSUMED_MSSG[i]) {
                System.out.println("PROCESS SYNC ERROR AT INDEX: " + i);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
        /* inform the user that synchroniozation was succesful, then exit */
        System.out.println("SYNC SUCCESFUL!");
    }
}
```

If there are any improvements you would like to offer, I'm happy to listen. Especially to the die-hard Java coders, I'm sure there's something that goes against the standard Java practice in here!

Comment: Port no. < 1024 are generally blocked; because those are reserved by the system. That's why you were facing difficulty.